# Drop-down submenus overlap, how do I fix this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, superfish

I rendered this menu with [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) and the Supersubs plugin:

[image: Superfish menu]

As you can see, the submenu that originates from parent "Long long long submenu item" isn't positioned correctly. I know what I need to do, but not how to execute it.

First, I need to know the width of the parent menu. I then need to set the submenu's `left` attribute to that width + 5px (I used padding) + 1px (so that the parent menu and submenu are not directly connected to each other). How do I do this for all menu items?

Keep in mind that the width of a menu is not fixed, since Supersubs adjusts the width to the longest item.

Comment: Please provide us with some of your example code - Superfish only uses scripting to add the hover class for IE browsers, everything else should be adjusted in the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm close...

```
$("ul#menu > li > ul ul").each(function() {
    $(this).css("left", $(this).parent().parent().width() + 5 + 1);
});
```